# Is $\mathrm{d}x_i$ a 0-form or a 1-form?

Tags: differential-forms

I have just started studying differential forms and I understand that 0-forms are smooth real valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, 1-forms are linear combinations of $\mathrm{d}x_i$ with smooth functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ being coefficients, 2-forms are linear combinations of $\mathrm{d}x_i$∧$\mathrm{d}x_j$ with coefficients being smooth functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and so on. I understand that $\mathrm{d}x_i$, is the function that takes as input a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and returns it's $\mathrm{i}^{th}$ component. So is $\mathrm{d}x_i$ a 0-form or a 1-form? Because by the definition of $\mathrm{d}x_i$, it is a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ so it should be a 0-form. At the same time it can also be considered as a 1-form. And if the answer to the above is that it is both a 0-form and a 1-form, then while taking pullbacks, why do we define the pullback of 0-forms separately and the pullback of $\mathrm{d}x_i$ differently? Is it because the pullback of $\mathrm{d}x_i$ as 0-form should be one thing and its pullback as a 1-form should be another? That seems a little strange to me.

I am looking at [Ted Shifrin's lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nh5XFX0iKgE&index=81&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) if that helps.

Comment: You've bumped into the confusing issue that a linear function and its derivative (at any point) are the same map on the vector space. If any of my students had been bothered/confused, I would have addressed this point in the lectures. Hang in there!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $dx_i$ does not take a *vector* $p\in \Bbb R^n$ and spits out its $i$th component. That would be the scalar function $x_i$. Instead, $dx_i$ takes in a vector *field* $X$, and for each point / vector $p\in \Bbb R^n$ it takes the vector $X_p$ of the field at $p$ and spits out the $i$'th component. Thus $dx_i$ makes a vector field into a scalar function.

In general, a $k$-form takes in $k$ vector fields and spits out a scalar funciton (there are other requirements too, like antisymmetry and smoothness and such). This makes $dx_i$ into a $1$-form.

Finally, $x_i$, which we recall is the scalar function given by the $i$'th component of the position vector, is a $0$-form, and $d$ always increases the degree of a form by exactly $1$. More generally, for a scalar function $f$, $df$ is the $1$-form that takes in a vector field $X$, and at each point $p\in \Bbb R^n$ gives the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ along the vector $X_p$.

Comment: In the sense that OP is considering 2-forms, the standard inner product is NOT a 2-form because it doesn’t satisfy antisymmetry. He is considering wedge products of the $dx_i$ so the forms are inherently antisymmetric.

Comment: @OsamaGhani You're right. I've taken away the example.

Comment: I’d also point out that I don’t recall if Shifrin introduces differential forms as maps from vector fields. He actually does define them concretely as acting on vectors, so OP just to clarify, the vectors that the form acts upon are the tangent vectors at a point, not the position vector itself. A (smooth) assignment of vector to every point is what @Arthur refers to as a vector field :)

Comment: @OsamaGhani That would explain the confusion that the OP has. It's also a formulation that is bound to create this exact confusion in people just learning about it, so it seems like a strange choice in my opinion.

Comment: Correct. I first defined $dx_i$ as the dual basis to the standard basis on $\Bbb R^n$. Differential forms (still on open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$) then came from making the exterior algebra into a module over the smooth functions (without the fancy language).